# Gradle: try to skp sonarqube results in error

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a gradle script that uses Sonarqube plugin (org.sonarqube). If I let the publish task depends on it, it works fine.

The problem is to run sonarqube only if a condition is true. So I tried (as described in gradle documentation) all of these three statements:

```
sonarqube.enabled (false)
sonarqube.enabled=false
sonarqube.onlyIf { false }
```

Each results in an error, here the one I got trying the first statement

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Eclipse\workspace3.6\at.mic.hermes\build.gradle' line: 208

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'at.mic.hermes'.
> Could not find method enabled() for arguments [false] on org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeExtension_Decorated@412196.
```

To be sure to have not typo in the code I tried all statements with the test task, e.g.

```
test.enabled(false)
```

and this results (as expeted) in

```
:test SKIPPED
```

Any ideas what I made wrong / what must be changed? Thx in advance!

Frank

Comment: Where have you found this documentation about sonarqube.enabled and sonarqube.onlyIf ? Apart if this is a common Gradle feature for all extensions, this is not implemented in SonarQube plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem come from a name conflict. There are 2 objects named 'sonarqube':

- The SonarQube task
- The SonarQube extension

It seems to not break your build, but here when you write `sonarqube.enabled` it access to the extension (according to your stacktrace).

The solution is probably to disambiguate using `tasks.sonarqube.enabled`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N11143